# Fill new rows based on missing column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like that

| week | co_week | Revenue | Cohort_index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19/09/2021 | 01/10/2021 | 120 | 0 |
| 19/09/2021 | 03/10/2021 | 150 | 1 |
| 19/09/2021 | 06/10/2021 | 223 | 2 |
| 19/09/2021 | 07/10/2021 | 256 | 4 |
| 19/09/2021 | 08/10/2021 | 340 | 5 |
| 20/09/2021 | 06/10/2021 | 126 | 0 |
| 20/09/2021 | 07/10/2021 | 234 | 1 |

Now I'd like to check if one `cohort_index` is missing (3 in this case) , then insert a new row with the missing index , rest of column values are copied from the previous row while updating the data frame index.

Desired Output :

| week | co_week | Revenue | Cohort_index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19/09/2021 | 01/10/2021 | 120 | 0 |
| 19/09/2021 | 03/10/2021 | 150 | 1 |
| 19/09/2021 | 06/10/2021 | 223 | 2 |
| 19/09/2021 | 06/10/2021 | 223 | 3 |
| 19/09/2021 | 07/10/2021 | 256 | 4 |
| 19/09/2021 | 08/10/2021 | 340 | 5 |
| 20/09/2021 | 06/10/2021 | 126 | 0 |
| 20/09/2021 | 07/10/2021 | 234 | 1 |

I can't hard-code the new raw since the data is huge!

```
new_raw = DataFrame({"week": 19/09/2022, "co_week": 06/10/2021, "Revenue": 223 ,"Cohort_index":3})
df = df.append(new_raw, ignore_index=False)
```

Comment: Whats happens if `Cohort_index=1` instead `Cohort_index=2`?

Comment: Sorry , I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: For test error use `print (df[df.duplicated(['week','Cohort_index'], keep=False)])` - get indices with same values per `week`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) temporarily, [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with `ffill`, then [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and restore columns in order:

```
out = (df
  .set_index('Cohort_index')
  .reindex(range(df['Cohort_index'].max()+1), method='ffill')
  .reset_index()[df.columns]
)
```

output:

```
         week     co_week  Revenue  Cohort_index
0  19/09/2021  01/10/2021    120.0             0
1  19/09/2021  03/10/2021    150.0             1
2  19/09/2021  06/10/2021    223.0             2
3  19/09/2021  06/10/2021    223.0             3
4  19/09/2021  07/10/2021    256.0             4
5  19/09/2021  08/10/2021    340.0             5
```

##### per group

You can do the same in a [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

```
out = (df
   .groupby('week', as_index=False)
   .apply(lambda g: g.set_index('Cohort_index')
                     .reindex(range(g['Cohort_index'].max()+1), method='ffill')
                     .reset_index()
          )
   .droplevel(0)[df.columns]
)
```

output:

```
         week     co_week  Revenue  Cohort_index
0  19/09/2021  01/10/2021      120             0
1  19/09/2021  03/10/2021      150             1
2  19/09/2021  06/10/2021      223             2
3  19/09/2021  06/10/2021      223             3
4  19/09/2021  07/10/2021      256             4
5  19/09/2021  08/10/2021      340             5
0  20/09/2021  06/10/2021      126             0
1  20/09/2021  07/10/2021      234             1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with `method='ffill'` parameter after convert `Cohort_index` to index by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), last convert `index` to columns and set original ordering by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df = (df.set_index('Cohort_index')
        .reindex(range(df['Cohort_index'].max() + 1), method='ffill')
        .reset_index()
        .reindex(df.columns, axis=1))
print (df)
         week     co_week  Revenue  Cohort_index
0  19/09/2021  01/10/2021      120             0
1  19/09/2021  03/10/2021      150             1
2  19/09/2021  06/10/2021      223             2
3  19/09/2021  06/10/2021      223             3
4  19/09/2021  07/10/2021      256             4
5  19/09/2021  08/10/2021      340             5
```

EDIT: Solution working per groups created if difference is less like `0`:

```
g = df['Cohort_index'].diff().lt(0).cumsum()

df = (df.set_index(['Cohort_index'])
        .groupby(g.tolist())
        .apply(lambda x: x.reindex(range(x.index.max() + 1), method='ffill'))
        .droplevel(0)
        .reset_index()
        .reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
        )
print (df)
         week     co_week  Revenue  Cohort_index
0  19/09/2021  01/10/2021      120             0
1  19/09/2021  03/10/2021      150             1
2  19/09/2021  06/10/2021      223             2
3  19/09/2021  06/10/2021      223             3
4  19/09/2021  07/10/2021      256             4
5  19/09/2021  08/10/2021      340             5
6  20/09/2021  06/10/2021      126             0
7  20/09/2021  07/10/2021      234             1
```