# Fill missing cohort indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like that

| week | Revenue | Cohort_index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 19/09/2021 | 120 | 0 |
| 19/09/2021 | 150 | 1 |
| 19/09/2021 | 223 | 2 |
| 19/09/2021 | 256 | 4 |
| 20/09/2021 | 340 | 0 |
| 20/09/2021 | 126 | 1 |
| 20/09/2021 | 234 | 2 |

Now I'd like to check if `cohort_index` is missing (3 in this case for date 19/09/2021 & also 3 for 20/09/2021) , then insert a new row with the missing index.

> Maximum number of indices will be decreasing so let's say for 19/09/2021 the
> maximum number of cohort index is 4 , so the next date 20/09/2021 will
> have 3 indices.. and I need to fill all missing indices from the minimum to maximum

rest of column values are copied from the previous row except `Revenue` that will be filled with `0` while updating the data frame index.

> Data is more granular than what I have posted , so for every date and every cohort_index I
> have different countries and different device types.

Desired Output :

| week | Revenue | Cohort_index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 19/09/2021 | 120 | 0 |
| 19/09/2021 | 150 | 1 |
| 19/09/2021 | 223 | 2 |
| 19/09/2021 | 0 | 3 |
| 19/09/2021 | 256 | 4 |
| 20/09/2021 | 340 | 0 |
| 20/09/2021 | 126 | 1 |
| 20/09/2021 | 234 | 2 |
| 20/09/2021 | 0 | 3 |

I think a `For loop` is needed , but I can't get my head around it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fill new rows based on missing column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73798059/fill-new-rows-based-on-missing-column-values) look at both answers, the "per group" methods. You might have to remove `method="ffill"` from the `reindex` call and call `fillna` on each column as you have different filling rules per different columns

Comment: It was also my question BTW , the only problem with the proposed answer is when the max cohort_index for a certain date is 5 for example in the original data , while the correct maximum should be 10 .. then it will only fill missing indices until 5 , but I want to fill until 10 ... it's because of this line `range(df['Cohort_index'].max()+1`

Comment: if you know the maximum can't you just use `range(your_known_max+1)` instead of inferring it from the data?

Comment: yes I thought about that , but that'd mean for every date I'll have the same maximum number of indices , while it should decrease over time.

Comment: how the max is determined or how to determine that it needs to decreased or in other words what the max is for each of the weeks.

Comment: the maximum cohort_index for the first date I determine by myself , then for all subsequent dates it will decrease by one , so if the first date in the dataset is 19/09/2021 , and the maximum I specify is 10 , then for 20/09/2021 , the maximum index should be 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit more tricky than I'd like but it should work. Could be simplified a little if there was a way to get current group number in groupby apply, is there?

```
columns = df.columns
max_cohort = 4
df["ngroup"] = df.groupby('week').ngroup()

out = (
 df.groupby('week', as_index=False)
   .apply(lambda g: g.set_index('Cohort_index')
                     .reindex(range(max_cohort + 1 - max(g["ngroup"])))
   )).droplevel(0).reset_index()[columns]

out["week"] = out["week"].fillna(method="ffill")
out["Revenue"] = out["Revenue"].fillna(0)
```

results is

```
          week  Revenue  Cohort_index
0  19/09/2021     120.0             0
1  19/09/2021     150.0             1
2  19/09/2021     223.0             2
3  19/09/2021       0.0             3
4  19/09/2021     256.0             4
5  20/09/2021     340.0             0
6  20/09/2021     126.0             1
7  20/09/2021     234.0             2
8  20/09/2021       0.0             3
```

Comment: brilliant , `ngroup`  should solve it , thanks